# how do I run c program without using ./?

Tags: unix

I need to program a c program like "a standard unix filter". I obtained a sample correct program and it was able to run the compiled c program without using "./"
I tried the same in my c program and I get an illegal command error with alternate commands found in bin. Is there some special alias or code that I need in my program to run the c program without ./ ?

Comment: There's nothing to do about C, but shell Path.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about adding the current directory to `PATH`.

Comment: @devnull: How is that off topic?

Comment: @KeithThompson It's off-topic because it's not about programming but about general usage of an operating system.

Comment: @KeithThompson It's off-topic because it's something that has been asked and answered well over a million times.

Comment: Put your program to the path of the operating system. ./ instructs the operating system to load from the local folder.

Comment: I don' think changing path is the answer that I want... I was able to put sample program in local file and it was still able to run it as table instead of ./table

Comment: @lifejuggler `PATH=$PATH:.`. However, this is considered dangerous and highly discouraged.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20023928/827263

Comment: Good question btw. A lot of people wonder about this, and everyone who know it think they are above the world, good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't about C; it's about executing your own programs in general, presumably on a Unix-like system.

If you copy the executable into a directory that's in your `$PATH`, you can execute it just by typing the name at a shell prompt.

Common practice is to create a `bin` directory directly under your `$HOME` directory, and prepend `$HOME/bin` to `$PATH` in your `$HOME/.bash_profile`. For example:

```
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

(You could also add `.` to your `$PATH`, but this is *not* recommended; it makes it too easy to execute things accidentally.)

Comment: I would add that invoking `/lib/ld-linux.so.2 your_program` (substitute with appropriate dynamic linker) would actually launch program even if it have not execution rights. Sometimes useful on bad filesystems that doesn't support UNIX access permissions.

Comment: @keltar: Perhaps, but unlikely to be useful to the OP.