# How to explain './' prefix before the name of an executable in terminal?

Tags: c, unix, terminal

Every time I compile a C program, say with the **cc** compiler, I get an executable in the current directory. Now if I want to run it, instead of typing out just `a.out` or `name_of_executable`, I have to prefix that with this combination `./a.out`.

I understand the meaning behind `.` (link to the current directory) and `..` (link to its parent directory), also that `/` is a separator between directory names.

But what is the meaning of `./`? Is it just a formal way to separate between referring to a name of something, and the intention to run that something (because you can't have `/` in your filename)?

Comment: I thought when you type a program name it uses the `PATH` to determine where to find the program, _unless_ you have explicitly stated in which directory to look.  `./` accomplished that.  (Really important to do if you have system administrator rights, else who knonws what program you may execute.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you type the name of an executable program, the shell searches for it in a sequence of directories whose names are stored in the `$PATH` environment variable.

The current directory, `.`, normally isn't (*and shouldn't be*) in your `$PATH`. So if you type just `a.out`, the shell won't find it -- unless there happens to be a `/usr/bin/a.out`, or `/usr/local/bin/a.out`, or ....

Why shouldn't `.` be in your `$PATH`? (Sometimes, on some systems, it is.) Because it creates a security hole. If `.` is at the front of your `$PATH`, then if you `cd` to a directory that happens to contain a command called `ls`, it's very easy to execute it accidentally, with arbitrarily bad consequences. Even if `.` is at the end of `$PATH`, you can still run into problems if the little program you just compiled, or the script you just wrote, happens to have the same name as a standard command. I've seen a lot of people becoming very confused because the named a test program `test`, but typing `test` runs `/bin/test`.

A **command** can be either a built-in command (provided by the shell) or the name of an executable file. If you type `ls`, the shell finds an executable file called `ls` in one of the directories named in your `$PATH`. If you type `a.out`, there is no executable file of that name in any of the directories named in `$PATH` -- thus the error message.

Typing a *path* to the executable file (even a relative path like `./a.out`) causes the shell to bypass the `$PATH` search; you're telling the shell exactly where to find the executable file rather than asking the shell to search for it.

Comment: How could you then explain the warning `-bash: a.out: command not found` when typing in `$ a.out`? It uses the word __command__, not file, or is this just semantics?

Comment: A **command** can be either a built-in command (provided by the shell) or the name of an executable file. If you type `ls`, the shell finds an executable file called `ls` in one of the directories named in your `$PATH`. If you type `a.out`, there is no executable file of that name in any of the directories named in `$PATH` -- thus the error message.

Comment: A file that is executable is a command. Not all files are commands. (Similarly, not all commands are *files*; a shell typically has a couple of built-in commands).

Comment: +1 for why `.` should not be in `$PATH`

Comment: @KeithThompson well done! I'd love it if you included your comment in the answer too. Thank you so much.

Comment: +1: *"I've seen a lot of people becoming very confused because the named a test program test, but typing test runs /bin/test"*. I guess this was one of the most frequent mistakes last year at my university: `valgrind test != valgrind ./test`

Answer (score 4):

For security reasons, most UNIX's don't allow running a program from the current directory, only from your PATH variable. Imagine if you un-tarred a file that contained a command such as `ls` or `gcc` and it had a trojan horse installed? You could easily run it on accident.

Therefore, you have to use `./` to specify you want to run a command from the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

When you enter a name of the executable, UNIX appends the name to elements of the [`PATH` variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) to obtain the path to the executable. The current directory is *not* searched by default. When you prefix `./` to the name, you instruct the shell to look for the executable in the current directory denoted by a dot `.`

Note that you could add the current directory to the `PATH` in order to avoid typing `./` prefix, [but this is not recommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65700/is-it-safe-to-add-to-my-path-how-come/65707#65707).